# removing duplicates in a list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose you have a list of MyObject like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public int ObjectID {get;set;}
  public string Prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

How do you remove duplicates from a list where there could be multiple instance of objects with the same ObjectID.

Thanks.

Comment: Why should there ever be objects with the same ID (usually that is kept distinct for exactly this reason...)?
I suppose you could create a list of the IDs and stings (as a composite string) and then do a .Distinct() but I think there is something more fundamentally wrong if IDs are non-unique.

Comment: @soandos: He might have a way to get the same object in the list twice on accident.

Comment: @notfed: That is still indicative of something going wrong.

Comment: But if that something going wrong is in an external source then removing duplicates is necessary.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy()` and select the first item of each group to achieve what you want - assuming you want to pick one item for each distinct `ObjectId` property:

```
var distinctList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.ObjectID)
                         .Select(g => g.First())
                         .ToList();
```

Alternatively there is also `DistinctBy()` in the [MoreLinq project](https://morelinq.github.io/) that would allow for a more concise syntax (but would add a dependency to your project):

```
var distinctList = myList.DistinctBy( x => x.ObjectID).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, cool, this is it. Would myList = myList.... also work? Just looking to avoid creating a new list.

Comment: @frenchie: Yes of course, you can reassign to the same list variable

Comment: You can not avoid creating a new list when using linq. If you want to use the same list you have to modify it yourself using `list.Remove(item)` or `list.RemoveAt(index)`.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working for my list of objects. I still get duplicates returned. Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316343/groupby-to-remove-duplicates-from-ienumerable-list-of-objects

Comment: Any downsides to using something like MoreLinq?

Comment: nope - just the complexity cost of adding an external dependency

Comment: You can group with multiple properties with 
List<XYZ> MyUniqueList = MyList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 }).Select(g=> g.First()).ToList();

Comment: Very clever, +1!

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using the `Distinct()` method. But since that method uses the default equality comparer, your class needs to implement `IEquatable<MyObject>` like this:

```
public class MyObject : IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public int ObjectID {get;set;}
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        else return this.ObjectID.Equals(other.ObjectID); 
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ObjectID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Distinct()` method:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
myList.Add(new MyObject { ObjectID = 1, Prop1 = "Something" });
myList.Add(new MyObject { ObjectID = 2, Prop1 = "Another thing" });
myList.Add(new MyObject { ObjectID = 3, Prop1 = "Yet another thing" });
myList.Add(new MyObject { ObjectID = 1, Prop1 = "Something" });

var duplicatesRemoved = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That would make the code look so much elegant! and easy to read. :-)

Comment: Why is this better than the 3-line answer provided above? What does it do more?

Comment: It enables your objects to be compared. This will be needed for some other list features, too and objects wich have an ID (entities) should be comparable by their id.

Comment: @frenchie: I believe it is more elegant and readable than the `GroupBy` solution and unlike the `DistinctBy` solution, it works without adding extra libraries.

Comment: When I use this method and debug the list using a foreach loop, i still get duplicates. Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316343/groupby-to-remove-duplicates-from-ienumerable-list-of-objects

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom object comparer by implementing the IEqualityComparer interface:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then simply:

```
myList.Distinct(new MyObjectComparer())
```

Comment: Tried this, but I still get the duplicated list returned.